# Error: Multibinder not initialized by guice appears when spark job deployed to cloudera

Tags: apache-spark, guice, spark-streaming, cloudera-cdh

I am using guice architecture upon developing my spark strreaming program. It can run in my eclipse without any error. However, after compiling and deployed with spark-submit command, it returns an error:

```
Multibinder is not initialized.
```

After googling through, I noticed that this error only appears if we are using guice 3.0. But I am using guice 4.0. My spark version is 1.5.2, and my cloudera version is 5.3.2. Is there any work around on this error?

Comment: I am not at all sure if true, but it sounds like you have an injection for some multi binding that is never initialised. You can initialise multibinding by doing: Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), MyClass.class); This was, there is an empty set that can be injected for that.

Comment: The codes are running in Eclipse. This error appears when I upload my FAT-Jar to cloudera. I have initialised Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), MyClass.class) as this too. It returns me that error and is very weird. As for workaround, I use annotation binding instead of Multibinding.

Comment: Maybe your fat jar pulls in a different version of guice transitively. You can do gradle dependencies to see if it comes from anywhere else. Or unpack your fat jar and look in it? As far as I know it is rather random which class is used if the same class in 2 versions is on the classpath